# Really trying to like CodeContracts in C#

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I am finally playing catchup with everything new that has been added in to the .NET 3.5/4.0 Frameworks. The last few days I have been working with CodeContracts and I am really trying hard to like them. I am curious what other people think of the implementation of CodeContracts in C#? Specifically, how are people organizing things like Contract classes for interfaces, contract methods for Contract Invariants etc?

I like the validation that contracts provide, at first glance they look great. With a few simple lines I can get some nice build checking before I even run my code. Unfortunately, I am having a hard time getting over the feeling that the way that code contracts are implement in C#, they are cluttering up my code more than they are documenting contracts. And to take full advantage of contracts, I am littering my code with assumptions and asserts etc (which I know some will say is a good thing); but as some of my examples below will show, it turns a single simple line in to 4 or 5 lines, and doesn't really add sufficient value in my opinion over alternative approaches (i.e., asserts, exceptions etc).

Currently, my greatest frustrations are:

Interface Contracts:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IInterfaceContract))]
  public interface IInterface
  {
    Object Method(Object arg);
  }

  [ContractClassFor(typeof(IInterface))]
  internal abstract class IInterfaceContract
  {
    private IInterfaceContract() { }

    Object IInterface.Method(Object arg)
    {
      Contract.Requires(arg != null);
      Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object>() != null);
      return default(Object);
    }
  }
```

This feels like such a cludge to me, I wish there was a cleaner way to document requirements, either via attributes or some form of built in language support. The fact that I have to implement an abstract class that implements my interface, just so I can specify the contract seems tedious at best.

Code Bloat:

```
typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Object);
```

Requires several assumptions just to verify information that is readily available. I appreciate that all the analyzer knows is that it is operating on Type and thus must work on that limited knowledge, but it still frustrates me that a single line of code requires me to re-write as

```
var genericAction = typeof(Action<>);

Contract.Assume(genericAction.IsGenericType);
Contract.Assume(genericAction.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1);

genericAction.MakeGenericType(typeof(Object));
```

Just to keep things documented (yes I know I can use ContractVerificationAttribute to turn this off for a method/class etc, or SuppressMessageAttribbute to target specific messages, but that seems to defeat the purpose as your code would quickly become littered with suppressions etc.

In addition, taking a case like

```
  public class MyClass
    : IInterface
  {
    private readonly Object _obj;

    public Object Property
    {
      get
      {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Object>() != null);
        return _obj;
      }
    }

    public MyClass(Object obj)
    {
      Contract.Requires(obj != null);

      _obj = obj;
    }
  }
```

obj is required to be not null, and is set to a readonly field that cannot be changed, yet I am still required to add a "markup" method to my class so that my property requirement to not return null can be proven:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant()
{
  Contract.Invariant(_obj != null);
}
```

There is more, but I figured I have probably ranted enough, and I would really appreciate the insight of people much smarter than me to help me "like" Code Contracts and make this feeling of code clutter go away. Any insight on how to better structure code, workaround wonkiness issues etc would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if your interface contract class can actually implement your interface (I don't see why not, and will ensure that your contract class actually implements contract for all interface methods. I'm still reading about CC, but seems like it would be a good idea?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> This feels like such a cludge to me, I wish there was a cleaner way to document requirements, either via attributes or some form of built in language support.

The CC team have stated that using Attributes just isn't powerful enough, because you can't include things like lambdas in them. They *could* include things like `[NotNull]` but have [chosen not to do so](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/d36e7611-e867-4211-b6a5-b92a46db0f0b/) because they're trying to keep CC as general as possible.

One reason that CC is a library (rather than part of an extended C#) is that it is supported across *all* .NET languages.

You can read more about the team's reasoning [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/9e31b2fd-d549-440a-80e4-8170001c8152).

In terms of actually using this, so far I've just been keeping my interface contracts in the same file as the interface, which means it's all documented in the same place. It is something that should be improved upon :)

> Code Bloat [...]

Your second complaint is probably something that can be implemented -- I'd suggest posting it on [the code contracts forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/). (EDIT: Seems someone [already has](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/478b0f78-45f0-4577-96e4-641e983293d6/), but no answers yet.)

However, it will always be the case that under-specified contracts will need more assumptions surrounding them. If you run into a case like this in the .NET framework you can request that contracts be added in the [Missing Contracts on Libraries thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/codecontracts/thread/d8e2c2ad-de37-42ef-a854-02052d821975).

> In addition, taking a case like [...]

This [has been addressed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/c44d0dd0-e02f-4d85-a7e2-f6ca79c93a9c/). If you have an auto-property, you just have to add an non-null invariant and the pre-/post-conditions will be generated:

```
public class MyClass : IInterface
{
    private Object Property { get; set; }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void Invariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(Property != null);
    }
}
```

You'll probably end up with other invariants for your classes anyway, so it's not that big a deal.

Answer (score 12):

Yeah, contracts clutter things up, but I feel like it's worth it when [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) reads the code contracts and generates 25 unit tests and 100% code coverage for me.  If you haven't used PEX yet, then you're missing out on the biggest benefit of code contracts. Here's a starter guide for using [PEX with contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/pexandcontracts.pdf).

Comment: I saw the PEX session at PDC (http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/VTL01) last year and is a definite plus. It compliments test generation; as it takes care of bioler plate tests; but as I am sure you are well aware, even if it gives you 100% code coverage, I would not rely on PEX tests alone (coverage isn't everything :D).

Comment: Nice thing....and the tests will always be green, no matter how wrong your logic really is...the genrated unit tests just mirror the wrong logic. It's only useful for regression but too easily give you a good feeling about your wrong code...

Answer (score 9):

I really wanted to like it too, and went quite far with an implementation in a new project, 
until I gave up under the weight of small niggling issues I had with it.

I would love for Microsoft to resurrect Spec#. I know code contracts was written as a library to be available across languages, but even just the speed of static analysis cries out for compiler support.

This guy raises some of the same points: http://earthli.com/news/view_article.php?id=2183

Anyway, there was no one problem that was a deal-breaker, but an accumulation of irritations:

- Static analysis is very slow. You can set it to run in the background, but then it's very easy to ignore.
- Static analysis isn't great, for example:

  - It only handles simple control flow
  - It won't assume that readonly fields are invariant
  - Collections are not handled by the static checker (only runtime)
- No delegate contracts
- Doesn't work well with Resharper unless you actively suppress resharper warnings one way or another

  - Resharper is optimistic. It will assume a method parameter is not null, until you give it a hint that it might be - like `Contract.Assume(thing != null)`
- Can generate a lot of warnings and suggestions, sometimes stemming from an ambiguous source.

  - The moment any team member lets their attention slip, the number of warnings would become overwhelming for everybody
- The need to specify abstract contract classes for interfaces is pain.
- Runtime contracts use IL rewriting, which apparently doesn't play well with other rewriting solutions like PostSharp (I think .

  - As a result of IL rewriting, edit-and-continue can't be used
- Contracts stick very tightly to liskov substitution principle: Subtypes can never relax pre-conditions. I mean, good in principle, but I imagine it would be a pain when working with over-contracted 3rd party code.

Comment: The real pain is when all your data comes from an external source. For example, an ORM mapping a database to POCO objects. You have to setup ContractInvariantMethods defining the contract on each Auto-Property. You basically end up making assumptions everywhere, which is no different than the classic if-block checking which probably performs much faster when added up over the life of an application.

Answer (score 3):

If your are concerned about code bloat then I would encourage you to look at [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) as an alternative.

This will allow you to specify the contract in the aspect and then wrap any classes or methods of classes in the contract.  If your contract is going to be used in more than one class then this would be a cleaner way to implement this.

Unfortunately the support for AOP in C# is not great but there are a couple of libraries that add this functionality.

And as I also have the same feeling towards other C# implementations as you have found with Contracts it all seems fine at first until you lift the hood and start using it in a serious fashion.

Comment: I like the idea of AOP, and as you have mentioned the C# support is not fantasic. PostSharp is a good framework, granted I have only worked with it a little. Are their any others that you have used? What did you find to be the best given serious use? any?

Comment: I'm still trying to convince work that AOP is worth using lol, I've only used it in my own time with Spring and Java. But there where a couple of other questions on stackoverflow about AOP in .NET that I remember reading.

Comment: Also another alternative would be to user Proxies or Interceptors and the castle project has a project http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html for dynamic proxies.

Comment: I find one of the best things about CC is the static checker. There aren't any alternatives for this AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 which can save you some time creating code contracts for interfaces and abstract classes: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I find the interface implementation great. It's not cluttering your interface or your regular code, and you can neatly store it in some folder in your solution, or in the same class file as your interface, whichever you like most.

Why are you **required** to add the object invariant? You are only required to add as much as you feel necessary.

I understand your point about code bloat, but I guess that's the trade-off with Code Contracts. Extra checks/security means extra codes, at least how it's currently implemented. I'd try to keep as much contracts as possible on the Interfaces, that should at least help you ease the code bloat pain.

Comment: I agree that the interfaces can be managed, and are not the biggest issue I have come across. You are definitely right in that they can be organized away. 

The ObjectInvariant is not required, but as I had mentioned not adding it would potentially result in a lot of SuppressMessage or ContractVerification attributes. The reason I say this, is I hate having warnings sitting in my TaskList. As such, I would either want to correct the issue (ObjectInvariant) or Suppress the message. 

True on the trade-offs; the wins are why I am trying to like them :D